# MySQL query result that use value of other fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for something like `format()` in other programming languages in MySQL query. The expected result is text that has values from other fields.

For example, something like

`select formatted from table where formatted=stringformat('some text {0}, {1} some text.', field1, field2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
SELECT CONCAT('some text ', field1, ', ', field2, ' some text.') FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### create a column in query and give it any alias to get result in. see this example.

SELECT ('some text, ' + tb.Col1 + ', ' + tb.Col2)    AS    ColName
 FROM
  MyTable   tb

Comment: Declare Varchar(max) variable above. set 'ColName' value to variable. and use Variable's value or print to view 'ColName'